# Consider the action of $S_3$ on $C^3 = \{ (x,y,z) | x + y + z = 0\}$. Show that $\rho$ is irreducible.

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

The action is defined as

$\rho_g (x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_{g(1)}, x_{g(2)}, x_{g(3)})$. For example:

if $g=(12)$, then $g(2,3,-5) = (3,2,-5)$. I understand that the action just permutes the elements, but I have no idea how to show the representation is irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

How to begin: a putative nontrivial proper subrepresentation would be $1$-dimensional.